# Convertir en popoup vista parcial

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, asp.net, asp

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC5, tengo una vista index en la cual tengo un `WebGrid`, desde la cual llamo a mi vista parcial, todo el código de llamar a la vista parcial desde el controlles marcha bien, el problema es que cuando la llamo no se muestra popoup.

```
<div style="margin-top: 17px;">
        @{
            var grid = new WebGrid(
                canPage: true,
                rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
                canSort: true,
                ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

            grid.Bind(Model.Content, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

            @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new {id = "grid"}, // id for ajaxUpdateContainerId parameter
                fillEmptyRows: false,
                tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover",
                mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("PhoneId", "ID"),
                    grid.Column("Model", "Model", style: "col-lg-4"),
                    grid.Column("Company", "Company", style: "col-lg-3"),
                    grid.Column("Price", header: "Price", format: @<text>@String.Format("{0:C}", item.Price) </text>),
                    grid.Column(header: "Action", canSort: false, style: "action",
                        format: @<text>
                                    @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/phone/details/" + item.PhoneId + "' id='" + item.PhoneId + "' title='Detail'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'> </span> </a>")
                                    @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/phone/edit/" + item.PhoneId + "' id='" + item.PhoneId + "' title='Edit'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'> </span> </a>")
                                    @Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' href='/phone/delete/" + item.PhoneId + "' id='" + item.PhoneId + "' title='Delete'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </span> </a>")
                                 </text>)

                    ));
        }

    </div>

}

<!-- modal placeholder-->
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Appjs/phones.js")
}
```

Me parece que el problema es que no esta llegando a `phone.js`
Cuando hago click en Details llama a mi vista parcial Details, pero no se convierte en popoup.

Cuando hago click en Detail debo de tener la etiqueta de anclaje que me parece es esta: `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"`, de ahí viene el script que no me deja poner el editor al final de ese código apunta a un js que se llama `phone.js` pero no se por que no funciona.

Comment: Utilizas Jquery? este editor te deja poner muchísimo código. Fijate de editar la pregunta y agregar el código que falta.

Comment: ¿Por que sale así? este es el problema que tengo.

Comment: Utilizo JavaScrip

Comment: No puedo explicarme mas por que este editor no me permite poner mas código

Comment: Hola Pedro, buenas tardes, puedes colocar una mayor cantidad de código utilizando https://gist.github.com/ Saludos

Comment: fredyfx, aca tengo el link completo explicando mi problema. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/e48a32f0-ef31-4d2e-b97a-bf386b3f4fde/popoup?forum=aspnetmvces

Comment: Pregunta: ¿cuando dices popoup te refieres a popup? Es que sólo lo he visto escrito así en las dos preguntas que has hecho sobre el tema y me chirría al leerlo

Comment: Por lo que veo en el código, y corrígeme si me equivoco, estás usando Bootstrap. ¿Podrías verificar que se están incluyendo los archivos de Bootstrap correctamente en el proyecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione

```
@Html.Raw("<a data-modal='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' href='/phone/details/" + item.PhoneId + "' id='" + item.PhoneId + "' title='Detail'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'> </span> </a>")
```

Gracias fredyfx, ya lo habías hecho en el botón esta es la etiqueta de anclaje.

Comment: perfecto! sigue adelante con todo el power 2.0! de nada

Comment: por cierto, perteneces a Comunidades Microsoft Perú?

Comment: No, solo al msdn